# How to show tabBar then segue to other viewController and return to this?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, tabbar

I have some viewControllers, I show the first viecontroller in tabBarController. Then I show other viewCOntroller from a button.
The next viewController haven't tabBar, but if I want return to the first viewController in TabBar this not whow the tabBar.

Can't I use this code:

```
 myviewController *viewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Vista1" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"vist2"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController animated:NO];
```

How can I declare a instantiation of tabBar index 1 view?
How can I solve this and show the firstView how first time was showed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to return to the number one viewController for example.

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
```

you can specify the desired index of the tabBar controller